# Intune Autopilot Powershell Script as an win32 app Error only in autopilot

Tags: powershell, microsoft-graph-api, intune, autopilot

I try to install a Programm with a Powershell Script ober Intune Autopilot.
This Script runs into an Error only in Autopilot.
It can be run ober the company Portal or with right click run with powershell.

The Script installs the Module Microsoft Graph to connect to azure and read some data.

But when the script is run over autopilot in user context i get following error:

```
original:
Get-Command : Die Benennung "Connect-MgGraph" wurde nicht als Name eines Cmdlet, einer Funktion, einer Skriptdatei oder 
eines ausführbaren Programms erkannt. Überprüfen Sie die Schreibweise des Namens, oder ob der Pfad korrekt ist (sofern 
enthalten), und wiederholen Sie den Vorgang.Get-Command : Die Benennung "Connect-MgGraph" wurde nicht als Name eines Cmdlet, einer Funktion, einer Skriptdatei oder 
eines ausführbaren Programms erkannt. Überprüfen Sie die Schreibweise des Namens, oder ob der Pfad korrekt ist (sofern 
enthalten), und wiederholen Sie den Vorgang.

translated:
Get-Command: The naming "Connect-MgGraph" was not used as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or
of an executable program. Check the spelling of the name or whether the path is correct (if
included), and repeat the operation.Get-Command: The naming "Connect-MgGraph" was not used as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or
of an executable program. Check the spelling of the name or whether the path is correct (if
included) and repeat the process.
```

The Errorcode from powershell is the following:

```
original:
Es ist nicht möglich, einen Index auf ein NULL-Array anzuwenden.

translated:
It is not possible to apply an index to a NULL array.
```

The follwoing Code is used to get the Error:

```
$targetParameter = (Get-Command Connect-MgGraph).Parameters['AccessToken']

if ($targetParameter.ParameterType -eq [securestring]){
    Connect-MgGraph -AccessToken ($token |ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText -Force)
}
else {
    Connect-MgGraph -AccessToken $token
}
```

I tried multiple Versions from the Grapg Api because of that I set the requiered Version on 2.5.

The Script runs over COmpany Portal and with right click run with powershell.

Comment: By default, PowerShell [auto-loads](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Modules#module-auto-loading) modules it can discover via the dirs. listed in `$env:PSModulePath`.
Auto-loading can be disabled / modified via the `$PSModuleAutoloadingPreference` preference variable. If a command from a given module cannot be found, the potential causes are:
(a) the module isn't installed; (b) the module is installed in a nonstandard directory; (c) auto-loading has been disabled. `Get-Module -List | % Path` lists the paths of all discoverable modules.

Comment: The error message tells you that no `Connect-MgGraph` command has been loaded into the current session; use the previous comment to diagnose why. The null-array error is just a follow-on problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution:

I had installed my modules with `-Scope CurrentUser`.
Because of that, `Connect-MgGraph` couldn't be used with Autopilot.

I removed the `-Scope` argument and now it works, though I'm unclear on why, given that it worked in other invocation scenarios.

Comment: If you install a module with `-Scope CurrentUser`, it is installed in a directory that is specific to that user and will only auto-load _for them_.
By contrast, installation with`-Scope AllUsers` - which requires _elevation_ (running as administrator) - installs to a directory where it will auto-load for _all_ users.

Comment: The implication is that your Autopilot task run with a _different_ user identity than the one you used when you installed the module with `-Scope CurrentUser`.